# Multiple Criteria In Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I know you can do a 1 to 1 relationship in a case statement like such

```
Select case userID when '12345' Then '12' Else userID End from userInformation
```

and I don't think you can add 2 criteria in here, but is it possible (if not how could i add a 2nd criteria) to say

```
Select case userID when '12345' And status is 'Active' Then '12' Else userID End from userInformation
```

Comment: @RickS hit the wrong tag I have SQL 2005.  I'll test and see if same principle applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a slightly different syntax:

```
 Select case WHEN userID = '12345' And status = 'Active' Then '12' Else userID End 
 from userInformation
```